# Archive fails with error archive Unable to read GoogleService-Info.plist at path Xcode 10.1

Tags: xcode, firebase

It's the first time I go through the process of archiving my app and myy problem is that when I build the projects it builds fine, it runs fine both on simulator than physical iPad, but when I do choose `Archive` it fails with the error message `Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code` `31merror: Unable to read GoogleService-Info.plist at path`.
Following other posts here on SO, I made sure that in `Build Phases/Copy Bundle Resources` `GoogleService-Info.plist`is present. I also checked that `GoogleService-Info.plist` Target Membership is correctly selected.
I tried to delete, throw it into trash and re-add it to the project by drag and drop. I restarted Xcode but nothing solved it. 
Any ideas on what else I should have a look at?
Could it be related to my developer's certificate?
As always many thanks.

UPDATE:

I tried uninstalling the pods and reinstalling them but with no changes.
I downloaded again the `GoogleService-Info.plist`from Firebase but also that didn't make a difference.

Update 2:

I deleted the firebase app and recreated one.
Re-downloaded the `GoogleService-Info.plist`and it's working ok..both on iPad and simulator.

but still archive fails not been able to read the `GoogleService-Info.plist`..

I'm actually deploying for iOS 9.3 and up..can it have something to do with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a few days of comparing this app with the other one, part of the same bundle, that Archives without a problem, I finally found the problem: A second `Fabric` script ..that should be used for `Answers` which was giving me problems and I just put aside using for the moment. I forgot to delete the script for it.
Now that I think about the script could be well be the reason for `Answers`not to be working ..time to investigate it ..

Well.. hopefully this will be of help to others..

The incriminated script:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

Comment: Thank @Vincenzo, you save my day

Comment: @truong luu. I'm very glad it helped. I know it could be very frustrating..

Comment: I migrated from fabrics to firebase/crashlytics  Now I am getting this error while archiving

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the very same error message "Unable to read GoogleService-Info.plist at path [...]" was happening during a simple build, and in my case, that was because my build path had a space in its name like "username/path/to/build/Blabla v0.0/GoogleService-Info.plist".

The executed command in Fabric didn't liked it and was unable to find the file GoogleService-Info.plist.

Comment: Same for me, the schema used had a space on the name so the path ended up being `ArchiveIntermediates/MY SCHEME WITH SPACE`

Comment: @rgkobashi I have a similar issue my Archie fails with the same error can you tell where exactly you place ur GoogleServicePlist file

Comment: sure, the path is `MyApp/GoogleService-Info.plist` but for the question asked I dont think that is relevant. If you can run your app on the simulator then the path for the .plist is fine, if the problem is when archiving it, then there is something different, which in my case was that my schema has an space

Comment: sure, but I dont use skype though, perhaps something more simpler, linked in or something

Comment: @rgkobashi my app runs fine in simulator but when archiving if I give the path MyApp/GoogleService-Info.plist it keeps on archiving forever if I change path of GooglePList it says [31merror: Unable to read Google Service plist at path /Users//Desktop/AppName/GoogleService-Info.plist[0m Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: what do you mean with `give the path`?
Have you check that the file actually exists on `/Users//Desktop/AppName/GoogleService-Info.plist`?

Comment: @rgkobashi Kindly add me on LinkedIn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216125/discussion-between-iminion-and-rgkobashi).

Comment: Was there a resolution to this? Is there a way to fix it without removing the spaces?

Answer (score 0):

None of the above applied to me. I tried removing & re-adding the `GoogleService-Info.plist`, confirming the `Build Resources`, confirming the targets, confirmed `Debug Information Format` in `Build Options`,  Ultimately, I resolved this issue by deleting the `Run Script` and re-adding it from scratch. Issue resolved